# Firebase Swift 3 Database crashes on setValue withCompletionBlock

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase on iOS with Swift 3.

When I use

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("child").setValue("value") { 
  (error: Error?, databaseReference: FIRDatabaseReference) in
    print("Error while setting value \(error)")
}
```

The app crashes on runtime with the following log:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidFirebaseData', reason: '(nodeFrom:priority:) Cannot store object of type _SwiftValue
>   at . Can only store objects of type NSNumber, NSString, NSDictionary,
>   and NSArray.'

I tried to use the same function but without the trailing closure and for some reason, it works!

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("child").setValue("value", 
  withCompletionBlock: { 
    (error: Error?, databaseReference: FIRDatabaseReference) in
      print("Error while setting value \(error)")
})
```

Is there something special about trailing closures and Swift 3?

Comment: Crash is because you can only set values / store object of type NSNumber, NSString, NSDictionary, and NSArray & the value which you are storing is not of any such type.

Comment: Not sure if that is the problem. I tried to use an NSString variable and pass it to setValue and it would still crash. But either case, not using a closure with regular Swift String seems to work.

Comment: @EmadToukan How did you get the Crash log on runtime? It may be a silly question to ask!

Comment: @AnuragSharma run the firebase app on a device and you should be able to see it in the Xcode console.

Comment: @EmadToukan obviously I know this but I was getting a crash after I sent build through testflight. And even the crash was not appearing while I debug. Now it is resolved! My NSTimer implementation was causing the crash and I got this report from Crashlytics.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*tl;dr: Firebase provides a `setValue(_ value: Any?, andPriority priority: Any?)` which is incorrectly matched when using a trailing closure with `setValue(_ value: Any?, withCompletionBlock: (Error?, FIRDatabaseReference) -> Void)`.*

**Solution**: When using an API that has many varieties, avoid using trailing closures. In this case, prefer `setValue(myValue, withCompletionBlock: { (error, dbref) in /* ... */ })`; do **not** use `setValue(myValue) { (error, dbref) in /* ... */ }`.

**Explanation**

This appears to be a Swift bug. As in other languages, such as Java, Swift generally chooses the most specific overload. E.g.,

```
class Alpha {}
class Beta : Alpha {}

class Charlie {
    func charlie(a: Alpha) {
        print("\(#function)Alpha")
    }
    func charlie(a: Beta) {
        print("\(#function)Beta")
    }
}

Charlie().charlie(a: Alpha()) // outputs: charlie(a:)Alpha
Charlie().charlie(a: Beta() as Alpha) // outputs: charlie(a:)Alpha
Charlie().charlie(a: Beta()) // outputs: charlie(a:)Beta
```

However, when overloaded functions match a trailing closure, Swift (at least, sometimes) selects the more general type. E.g.,

```
class Foo {
    func foo(completion: () -> Void) {
        print(#function)
    }
    func foo(any: Any?) {
        print(#function)
    }
}

func bar() {}
Foo().foo(completion: bar) // outputs: foo(completion:)
Foo().foo(any: bar) // outputs: foo(any:)
Foo().foo() { () in } // outputs: foo(any:)
// ^---- Here lies the problem
// Foo().foo(bar) will not compile; can't choose between overrides.
```

`Any?` is a more general type than `() -> Void` -- i.e., "anything, even null" is more broad than "a function receiving 0 parameters and returning something of type `Void`". However, the trailing closure matches `Any?`; this is the opposite of what you would expect from a language that matches the most specific type.

Answer (score -3):

While there is an accepted answer, which provides some clarity, explaining that it's a Swift bug is not really accurate. That being said, the explanation is accurate but not for this issue.

Allowing the closure to be added to setValue in the first place is the real bug.

A more accurate answer is that *there is no completion block/closure for the setValue function*, which is why it fails.

The specific function -setValue: does NOT have a closure, which is why it's crashing. i.e. it's an incorrect implementation in your code. Per the docs:

```
func setValue(_ value: Any?)
```

note that the setValue function does NOT have a closure and if you add one the function will have no idea what to do with that data.

To use a completion block/closure, you must call the correct function which is

```
-setValue:withCompletionBlock:
```

Bottom line is you can't randomly add a parameter or call to a function that's not designed to accept it.

This is obviously **not** valid but conceptually it's the same error.

```
    let a = "myString"
    a.append("x") { (error: Error?) }
```

In this case the compiler knows the the string.append function doesn't have a closure option and catches it before compiling.

So go a tad further, this code complies & runs but also generates an error

```
ref.child("child").setValue("value") { }
```

Again, setValue doesn't have a closure so this code is improperly implemented.

To clarify, given a class

```
class MyClass {
    var s = ""
    var compHandler = {}

    func setValue(aString: String) {
        self.s = aString
    }

    func setValue(aString: String, someCompletionHandler: completionHandler) {
        self.s = aString
        self.compHandler = someCompletionHandler
    }
}
```

Note that setValue:aString is a totally different function than setValue:aString:someCompletionHandler

The only parameter that can be based to setValue:aString is a String as the first and only parameter.

The setValue:aString:someCompletionHandler will be passed two parameters, a String in the first position and a completionHandler in the second position.

The actual completion block is the second parameter passed.

param1,  param2
------,  ---------------
string,  completionBlock

This is why

```
setValue(value) {}
```

is improperly formatted whereas

```
setValue(value, withBlock: {})
```

is properly formatted.

Comment: Thank you Jay for providing an answer. Even though that your answer is correct that a function does not take a trailing closure when the last parameter is not a function, but in this case there is a function that takes a closure as its last parameter:
`func setValue(_ value: Any?)`
`func setValue(_ value: Any?, withCompletionBlock block: @escaping (Error?, FIRDatabaseReference) -> Void)` --> This is the one that we discussing above.

The whole purpose of the trailing closure is to match the overload that get passed a function as a parameter (the setValue(value: withCompletionBlock:))

Comment: @EmadToukan I see what you are saying. The issue is that setValue doesn't have a closure. setValue:withCompletion does. The data in the closure is being passed/handled by the :withCompletion portion, not to the setValue portion.

Comment: exactly :-)

That's why I feel it's a bug in Swift, not my code.

Comment: @EmadToukan I am going to agree and disagree. Attempting to pass a closure to setValue when setValue doesn't accept a closure as a parameter is a coding issue. However - and this is the important part - Xcode should NOT let you pass a closure to a function that doesn't accept it in the first place - like in the a.append("x") {closure} example. Xcode stops that before compiling so it should also have stopped it with .setValue. To me, that's not a Swift bug IMO but more of a compiler issue or possibly in the Firebase API. You have an excellent question and it should be fixed either way.

Comment: setValue DOES accept a closure. Here is the function definition from the Firebase docs `func setValue(_ value: Any?, withCompletionBlock block: @escaping (Error?, FIRDatabaseReference) -> Void)`.

Comment: Looking again at your comments above, I see where the confusion is. When using trailing closures, Swift removes the parameter name for the closure and the closure is written in a block after the function, BUT that doesn't mean that Swift matches it with the function without the closure. Please refer to Trailing Closure from the Swift guide https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID102

Comment: If you review the accepted answer above, you'll see the bug. When calling `Foo().foo() { () in } // outputs: foo(any:)` where it should output instead foo(completion:). Swift is matching `Foo().foo() { () in }` with `func foo(any: Any?)` instead of `func foo(completion: () -> Void)` I hope this makes it more clear.

Comment: The confusion is stating the name of the function - there isn't a 'setValue' function. There's a setValue:value and a setValue:value:withCompletionBlock. They are two *separate functions* and have different parameters and behaviors. Re-read the Apple documentation at the link you've provided. Notice the name of the function *someFunctionThatTakesAClosure*. SetValue does not take a closure, and more importantly why would it when a function already exists that does take a closure, setValue:value:withCompletionBlock. Why would they have two functions that do the same thing? They are different!

Comment: Either way. Happy new year!

Comment: This is a bug in Swift.  When doing overload resolution we consider the solution set that upcasts to Any then to Any? to be equally bad as the one that converts the type variable lying around in the closure (twice, for some reason?), so we wind up picking the Any? conversion.  As a workaround you can use the explicit form of the function call.  Though, I would say a better approach is to avoid Any? like the plague.  It guarantees basically nothing about the value you're passing and is kind of a lazy way to get polymorphism without restrictions.

Comment: @CodaFi Can you please explain why you would pass a closure to a function that doesn't expect or use a closure? For example, why would you pass a closure to a function like String.append("x") {}, just like setValue("value") {}. What would the expected result be? You can down vote my answer all you like but until there's a solid explanation, it should be considered.

Comment: It doesn't matter why.  Any is a universal bridging target and optional upcasts have been a feature of the language since day one.  From that standpoint, "not having a closure" argument type is irrelevant.  The semantics may not make sense to you at a human level, but at the level of the language this kind of call is perfectly valid (which is what makes this a language *bug*).  This API call is crashing on the one hand because, yeah, you're passing it weird data, but on the other hand because it is poorly indicating the true type of values it can take.